# Can a Kashmir citizen get a visa for america?

Tags: visas, usa, kashmir

I am wondering how to find out about a tourism visa to America for a Kashmir born citizen? I am American and nosy?

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. The U.S. imposes no blanket bans against people born in any particular place, though the [circumstances of one's birth](http://www.csmonitor.com/World/Global-Issues/2010/0704/Locked-out-The-12-million-people-without-a-country-and-the-need-to-become-a-citizen) can certainly complicate the paperwork. Please do your initial research from the [U.S. State Department Tourism & Visa](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit.html), and if you still have questions, edit this one, being sure to note what kind of visa and whether it is Indian or Pakistani Kashmir.

Comment: Second part of the question: if they are here and like can they stay?

Comment: As with any country, they can stay as long as they are following the terms of their visa (before the expiration date, not participating in excluded activities, etc.). Beyond that, please read up on how to become a [U.S. permanent resident (green card holder)](http://www.uscis.gov/greencard) or to gain [U.S. citizenship](http://www.uscis.gov/us-citizenship).

Comment: What is the country of your passport?

Comment: kashmir is the country

Comment: Kashmir is not a country in the sense that it can issue passports. A passport for someone born in Kashmir would have to be issued by one of the nations controlling Kashmir.

Comment: @SusanTee StackExchange is not a regular forum like you might be used to using. It's designed as an Ask a Question, Get and Answer exchange. Comments are to clarify a question or an answer, not carry on a chat session, that is what the SE Chat is for. Please modify your original question with more details, or ask a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

Kashmir is not a country in and of itself. There is no entity authorized to issue Kashmir passports, nor is there any such thing as a Kashmir 'citizen'. At the moment, the total area inhabited by peoples who might identify themselves as "Kashmiri" are parts of Pakistan, India and the People's Republic of China.

Were a person of Kashmiri descent decide to want to come to the US, what they needed for that visit would depend on which of those three countries they are actually a citizen of and have a passport issued by.